# Replace Backslash with Forward Slash in a C++ CLI String (not std::string!)

Tags: string, replace, c++-cli, clr

first of all I already tried out some suggestions on Stackoverflow but they didnt work.

So what I want to do is to replace the backslashes in a filepath with a forward slash.

But im not using the std::string im using the System::String of C++ CLI.
So here is my code:

```
 private: System::Void bXMLFileDialog_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    ofdxml->FileName = "";
    ofdxml->DefaultExt = L".xml";
    ofdxml->AddExtension;
    ofdxml->Filter = L"XML-Datei (*.xml) | *.xml";

    try {
        if (ofdxml->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
            String^ filename = ofdxml->FileName;
            filename->Replace('\\', '/');
            tbLoadXML->Text = filename;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex) {
        MessageBox::Show("Ungültiger Pfad!");
    }
}
};
```

Any suggestions how this could work?

Comment: `C++` and `C++/CLI` (or `C++/CX`) are different languages.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah I know sry used the wrong tag

Comment: What problems are you seeing?  Compiler error?  Execution problems?  Add these details to your question.

Comment: Not a problem, you can edit the question and remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: Find a little unused space in your brain and store "strings are immutable".  And you'll never get this wrong again.  Fix: filename =  filename->Replace(...);